# Use Google AdMob without SDK

Tags: android, ios, admob

is there a way to use Google AdMob without the provided SDK for Android or iOS?
I mean API base API or something like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible to load Google AdMob ads without using AdMob's SDK, There is no API-based solution for loading ads directly using API.

It's because there's a lot of background process which works internally to verify, load, cache, and showing ads to the device. It's very unlikely to have an API in the future too, for loading ads ourselves.